# How to modify SQLite query for retrieving data from DB

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I’m working on a Windows Phone 8 app. I’ve inserted data in SQLite, now I’m retrieving data from that by using this command as it was given in a tutorial:

```
("select * from Task").FirstOrDefault();
```

I can understand that it’s just giving first or default result, because of `.FirstOrDefault`, but I want to get all data. What will be the query? I have tried `("select * from Task").All()` also, but it’s giving an error.

Here’s the complete code:

```
/// Create the database connection.
dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH);
/// Create the table Task, if it doesn't exist.
dbConn.CreateTable<Task>();
/// Retrieve the task list from the database.
/// 

var existing = db.Query<Task>("select * from Task").FirstOrDefault();
if (existing != null)
{
    block3.Text = existing.Title;
    block4.Text = existing.Expense;

    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {
        db.Update(existing);
    });
}
```

Kindly suggest me how to modify the query for all results.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're writing SQL directly, [try this tutorial instead](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone).

Answer (score 0):

you can directly used it like this..

```
var list = db.Query<Task>("select * from Task;").Result
```

or if you are using async function used it with await like this..

```
var list = await db.Query<Task>("select * from Task;")
```

hope it helps you.